# resolveuri failed on bad bitmap uri when putting on GridView

Tags: android, gridview, bitmap, thumbnails

Hello I'm trying to develop android application that pulls all the image from my phone camera and display in GridView. However, I'm getting the following error:

```
01-11 09:38:38.890: I/System.out(6766): resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri:   /storage/sdcard0/DCIM/.thumbnails/1347279747819.jpg
```

In fact I'm getting a lot of this, which is why when I test it on my phone, I can see the scroll bar but no thumbnail displayed (except 2 images)

Here's my code that I thought relevant:

```
package org.dale.dalegetcontent1;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class GetContent1 extends FragmentActivity  implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

/** SimpleCursorAdapter, holds images and layout for the gridview */
SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    /** Initializes the Loader */
    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_content1);

    /** Getting a reference to gridview of the MainActivity layout */
    GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);

    /** Create an adapter for the gridview */
    /** This adapter defines the data and the layout for the grid view */
    mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
        getBaseContext(),
        R.layout.gridview,
        null,
        new String[] { "_data","_id"} ,
        new int[] { R.id.img},
        0
    );

    /** Setting adapter for the gridview */
    gridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    /** Loader to get images from the SD Card */
    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

    /** Defining item click listener for the grid view */
    OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

            /** Getting the cursor object corresponds to the clicked item */
            Cursor c1 = (Cursor ) arg0.getItemAtPosition(position);

            /** Getting the image_id from the cursor */
            /** image_id of the thumbnail is same as the original image id */
            String id = c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("image_id"));

            /** Creating a bundle object to pass the image_id to the ImageDialog */
            Bundle b = new Bundle();

            /** Storing image_id in the bundle object */
            b.putString("image_id", id);

            /** Instantiating ImageDialog, which displays the clicked image */
            ImageDialog img = new ImageDialog();

            /** Setting the bundle object to the ImageDialog */
            img.setArguments(b);

            /** Opening ImageDialog */
            img.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "IMAGEDIALOG");
           return ;
        }

    };

    /** Setting itemclicklistener for the grid view */
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_get_content1, menu);
    return true;
}

/** A callback method invoked by the loader when initLoader() is called */
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
    /** Getting uri to the Thumbnail images stored in the external storage */
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getContentUri("external");

    System.out.println("Thumb URI: "+uri.toString());

    /** Invoking the uri */
    return new CursorLoader(this, uri, null, null, null, null);
}

/** A callback method, invoked after the requested content provider returned all the data */
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor arg1) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(arg1);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
}
```

And my gridview.xml under layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/img_description"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And my activity_get_content1.xml under layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".GetContent1" >

<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks, happy to provide more info if required

Cheers, Dale

Comment: anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: Dear all, is there a reason why no one answering my question? I'm happy to provide more info

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add this permission in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```